# jQuery show() is not showing with slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to hide and show an article element using slide effect.when I load the page and click Home,if article is visible on screen, the js I've written hides it smoothly and great with no problem.but when I click the About Us Link,it shows article immediately without slide effect.

**Here is show and hide code + html + vanished CSS:**

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical">
        <li><a href=# onclick=home()>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=#about onclick=about()>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>Cuisines</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=#starters>Starters</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Main Dishes</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Desserts</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>Mezes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>Wine List</a></li>
        <li><a href=#gallery>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href=#contacts>Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<article class=vanished id=about>
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <div class="main-wrapper scroll">
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <img src=img/bazar-place.png alt=bazar-place width=222 height=150 class=about-img>
            <h4>Our Restaurant</h4>
            <p>Bazar is a restaurant located between the districts Haga and Vasastaden in Gothenburg with a focus on Turkish and Persian food of the best quality that creates opportunities for an exciting mix all the way, from appetizer to dessert.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <img src=img/belly.jpg alt=belly-dancing width=222 height=167 class=about-img id=belly>
            <h4>Events</h4>
            <p>Every Saturday from 21, we have Belly dancing at Bazar.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <img src=img/food.jpg alt=food-services width=222 height=167 class=about-img id=food>
            <h4>Food Services</h4>
            <p>Taste our famous pasta dish to the human price of 69 :- We offer 10% discount for take-away at our entire menu.</p>
            <p>At lunchtime you can choose from three Turkish pasta dishes or among two or three different main dishes. Ask about vegetarian options! Drinking, salad and coffee / tea included. Lunch can also be picked up.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper last clearfix">
            <img src=img/extra.jpg alt=extra-services width=222 height=167 class=about-img id=extra>
            <h4>Extra Services</h4>
            <p>We can help with everything from after work, kick-off to the birthday called with food and drink that lasts all night. Do you want more entertainment we can arrange live music and belly dancing.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function home(){

    if ($(".active") == [])
    {
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        var active = $(".active");
        active.css("display","inline-block");
        active.hide("slide",{direction:"left"},700);
        active.attr("class","vanished");

    }
}
function about(){
    if ($(".active") == [])
    {
        var hidden = $("#about");
        hidden.css("display","inline-block");
        hidden.show("slide",{direction : "right"},700);
        hidden.attr("class","active");
    }
    else
    {
        if ($("#about").attr("class") == "active")
        {
            return ;
        }
        else
        {
            var active = $(".active");
            active.css("display","inline-block");
            active.hide("slide",{direction:"left"},700);
            active.attr("class","vanished");
            var hidden = $("#about");
            hidden.css("display","inline-block");
            hidden.show("slide",{direction : "right"},700);
            hidden.attr("class","active");
        }

    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.vanished{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `if ($(".active") == [])` should work...try `if ($(".active").length === 0)`

Comment: You appear to have the order of arguments incorrect for both `.hide()` and `.show()`: http://api.jquery.com/show/. @Ian that'll "work" in the sense that it evaluates to a boolean (always `false` though :).

Comment: @MattBall Haha by "work", I meant "work as you expect"

Comment: Also, instead of `if ($("#about").attr("class") == "active")`, you might want to use `if ($("#about").hasClass("active"))`

Comment: And similarly to add/remove the classes - `active.addClass` and `active.removeClass`, but that's not as important

Comment: it's a mystery for me why anybody want to downvote this question. He's asking a normal question and provides details. What more do you want?

Comment: @IAlwaysAcceptAnswer they might be offended by the very-un-jQuery jQuery.

Comment: @Mathletics In these times it's like everybody get's offended about barely anything. And even then it would have been better if instead of just down voting  they would point out how the script could have been improved so he could learn from it.

Comment: so give me the right jquery Mathletics.I'm waiting

Answer (score 1):

this is before the hide/show: so it shows as a block, at that point.

```
 hidden.css("display","inline-block");
```

I would just put CSS in for that, then delete those lines.